# Split A CFC file into multiple files

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have been asked to update an old project. When i went into the cfc file it had over 3000 lines of code and over 100 cffunctions. I was wondering if i could split the cfc into multiple files whose cffunctions are logically grouped without having to change the code in any other pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run into a similar problem. I created the new cfcs and modified the original functions to call functions within the new cfcs.

For e.g

```
 <cffunction name="GetStuff" access="remote" returntype="Struct">
      <cfreturn createObject("component","myNewCFC").GetStuff(argumentCollection=arguments)/>
 </cffunction>
```

Comment: just remember that object creation in Adobe Coldfusion (don't know if you're using it or not) is expensive. using this approach you could see a performance hit.

Comment: With a CFC of that size, it would be reasonable to guess there are other design problems that are causing/may cause performance issues. If there's a constraint on the solution space - IOW, refactoring the application is not a consideration - this isn't a bad approach at this point.

Comment: Object creation is not very expensive on ColdFusion 8 and even less so on ColdFusion 9. If you choose this approach, be sure to pass any arguments along like: getStuff(argumentCollection=arguments);

Comment: rip747 if you're finding that object creation is expensive then you probably need to look at upgrading the underlying jvm that you're using to jdk 1.6.0_14+

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, but you might also want to look at using dependancy injection using ColdSpring or Lightwire, rather than using createObject() in your functions.

Comment: There was an edit suggestion here that may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/750

Comment: This was the answer that my supervisor gave as well. But he said that I wouldn't really have time for something like this. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor, Refactor, refactor...

simplest way might be using `cfinclude` to inject functions (mixin's)

Comment: Wouldn't be my approach - `<cfinclude>` in a CFC object never felt right to me. But +1 for refactoring.

Comment: This prevents future code from working with smaller objects - really the goal if you think about it.

Comment: the only issue you have with this approach is that under ACF you lost the ability of overloading methods in inheritance. Railo doesn't have this issue.

Comment: This is actually the approach that I took in the end. It was quick and easy (which is what the boss always wants). I do refactoring all the time, this was just code thats 10 years old. +1

Answer (score 2):

Question implies there's enough client code using this object that changing the calls elsewhere if the object's broken apart apart is burdensome. In this case treat the existing object as a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) - that is an object that provides unified interface to an underlying class hierarchy.

The way to approach producing the hierarchy is identifying those functions that should go together. Whenever I come across this problem the functions usually do not share any state, rather they are like `static` java methods, but if there are functions that share state they are a good candidate for this grouping. Otherwise it's usually functions that share the same input parameters or tend to have the same verbiage in their name (i.e. `saveMyData`, `loadMyData`, etc...).

Given that example, **copy** these functions into a new CFC (e.g. `MyData`) - at this point you may change the function names to eliminate repetition or improve their clarity (e.g. `MyData.load()`). Back in the original object (i.e. `BigCFC`) remove these functions' implementation and instead delegate the call to the newly created CFC (you may consider making the new CFC part of the old's composition). So it would look something like this:

```
<cffunction name="loadMyData">
  <cfargument name="id" type="numeric"/>
  <cfreturn variables.myData.load(arguments.id)/>
</cffunction>
```

Where `variables.myData` would be setup as part of the CFC's initialization.

Taking this approach means your existing client code is unaffected by the change, but still breaks apart everything into logic groupings, and positions new code to use the more granular CFCs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This way would work but it would take longer to implement. If I had more time for this project I might have taken this approach. Stil +1 from me for a comprehensive answer that answered the original question. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this would take too long? This is fast; it involves no change to the public API so other code is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and I just came across it randomly, but I thought I'd chime in here as it's something I've had to deal with on many occasions.

If the goal is simply to organise things better from a code management perspective (rather than say, to specifcially reduce the amount of methods in each CFC) then I'd advocate breaking the CFC down into multiple CFM pages and *including* them in the CFC. From a code management perspective, you can group several functions into a well named CFM file and it all becomes a lot easier to deal with. The calling code remains the same, as all the functions are still being instantiated in the CFC as before.

I have a bit of code I use in my init methods that automatically includes all the CFM files it finds in the same folder, and I house a single base.cfc in each folder along with the grouped functions.

e.g.

```
<cfscript>
    // Set CFC name
    Variables.sCFCName = 'appUtils';
    // Set folder
    Variables.sCFCFolder = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath());
    // Get CFC files
    Variables.qCFCFiles = directoryList(Variables.sCFCFolder, true, 'query');
</cfscript>

<!--- Init function --->
<cffunction name="init" access="public" returnType="any" output="false" hint="Constructor">
    <cfargument name="DSN" type="string" default="" hint="Datasource" />

    <!--- Set DSN --->
    <cfset Variables.DSN        = Arguments.DSN />

    <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>

<!--- Include CFC files --->
<cfoutput query="Variables.qCFCFiles">
    <cfif Variables.qCFCFiles.type EQ 'file' AND GetToken(Variables.qCFCFiles.name, 2, '.') EQ 'cfm'>
        <cfinclude template="#Variables.qCFCFiles.Name#" />
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```